# MonoTouch application iOS signing with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, signing

I have a problem.
I developed an application iOS with MonoTouch, Fantastic!!!
But now my customer asks me that wants to sign him the app, with his certificate.

Is there a solution?
It’s possible create a xcode source from monotouch???

I have read a –xcode command but I found little doc

Answer (score 3):

The `--xcode` option is deprecated. Once upon a time it was useful to debug some issues but better options exists today.

As for signing you can use the `codesign` command-line tool to (re)sign the application.

For an example just look at your build output (from MonoDevelop's Error List pad) to see the exact command line that MonoDevelop use to sign your application. Your client will opnly need minor adjustment (to the options) to re-sign it.

Comment: it is a shame for the command-xcode
I had read something but I could not find documentation
My problem, however, remains
I can't use the commandline to the customer
he needs xcde... 
Perhaps the only solution is to abandon monotouch
.......